# Abstract Static Classes Java

Tags: java, class, static, inner-classes

Okay, I want to create a bunch of nested classes to store final (constant), static variables for my application to access. Here is how I set it up. It isn't working as predicted and obviously I have something wrong...which I am sure is quite simple...

```
abstract public class FH_Primitive_Topo {

    public static class Draw_Specs extends FH_Primitive_Topo{
        public final float LineColour_Red   = 0.28f;
        public final float LineColour_Green = 0.46f;
        public final float LineColour_Blue  = 1.0f;
        public final float LineColour_Alpha = 1.0f;
    }
}
```

Can someone please point me in right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Describe _it isn't working_.

Comment: this is what enums are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static` in this context means only that the nested class does not have a reference to a parent class instance (allowing the nested class to be instantiated without an instance of the parent). It doesn't mean that you don't need to instantiate the inner class or that all its fields are static. In your example the constants are instance members, not static fields.

Make the constants static if you don't want to create an instance of the inner class.

It would seem preferable to me to use enums for these kinds of constants. Enums were designed to group constant values, and code coverage tools won't complain about uncovered paths  like they would with your approach (due to the default zero-arg constructors created for your classes).